# How to change any buttons colour after clicked in TKINTER PYTHON

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm wondering if anyone has experience in changing a buttons colour after clicked. Keep in mind i have around 50 buttons which are individually created (i want it this way, unless you can convince me). In my head im thinking of creating a Function which will change the colour but thats where the problem starts, I dont know how to make it change the CLICKED buttons colour (i dont want it to change a SET IN STONE button, JUST THE ONE CLICKED.)

If you can help send an example and ill be able to translate into my code!

Thanks

I tried to create a function that would change the button colour after its clicked.

Comment: Every button can have its own colors. Check the button `keys` method like so. b = tk.Button(); print(b.keys()). That will give you the button attributes like `background` and `foreground`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this is probably not the *best* way to implement this, but it will at the least get you started.

It should scale fine for 50 buttons, the only thing that really doesn't is the choice of colors (I figured you'd only need a few anyways). You will need to assign the buttons to variables if you haven't, you could initialize an array to 50 [0,0,0...] then use that instead of allocating 50 variables. In order to call the tkinter configure function and change the properties the "pointers" need to be stored somewhere (ex. 1 array[0...49], 1 vector[0...49], 50 variables) then passed into the OnButtonPressed function for this example to work.

The lambda function is necessary to pass parameters into the button command function call. If you find a way to not need the parameters, then delete the lambda and the parenthesis so you just have the name of the function (ex. tk.Button(command = MyFunction).

As a side note, the reason all my tkinter objects have tk. prefix is because I did this import: "import tkinter as tk"

```
import tkinter as tk

#Define on button press function...Parameteres are button object and specified color
def OnButtonPress(button, color = None):
    #match color:                               #USE THIS match IF YOU HAVE Python 3.10 or higher
    #    case 0:
    #        color = "Purple"
    #    case 1:
    #        color = "#17ff60"
    #    case _:
    #        color = "#919191" #Just Grey for None or invalid
    if color == 0: color = "Purple"
    elif color == 1: color = "#17ff60"
    else: color = "#919191"
    button.configure(background = color)
    return


#Make root object
root = tk.Tk()

#Define and create window
root.geometry("600x500")
root.title("Button Changes")
mainframe = tk.Frame(root, width = 600, height = 500)
mainframe.pack(anchor = "center")

#Define and create buttons...Must use lambda or partial to pass parameters to function
button00 = tk.Button(mainframe, text = "0", command = lambda: OnButtonPress(button00, 0), width = 10, height = 5, background = "Light Blue")
button00.pack(anchor = "n") 
button01 = tk.Button(mainframe, text = "1", command = lambda: OnButtonPress(button01, 1), width = 10, height = 5, background = "Light Blue")
button01.pack(anchor = "s") 
button02 = tk.Button(mainframe, text = "2", command = lambda: OnButtonPress(button02), width = 10, height = 5, background = "Light Blue")
button02.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you explain? I think the indentations are all correct.

Comment: Sorry my mistaken.

Comment: No problem, I trust you more than myself haha. I double checked the indentations. It is nap time though, 3:00 am